# Converting DVDs to Precisely Sized XviDs like “The Scene”

Tags: dvd, video-conversion, avi, xvid

I am hoping to *finally* watch the *Star Wars* movies (yes, yes, I know) and intend to watch them all in a row as a marathon. I would prefer not to have to constantly get up and change discs, so I thought it would be convenient if I could rip my discs to AVI files and put them on a single DVD+RW (6 movies × 700MB = 4200MB; DVD+RW = 4482MB, leaving enough space for some extras or rather to make them each 747MB or—somehow—dynamically adjusting their sizes to fit).

I ripped one of the movies to the hard-drive (yes, I took encryption into consideration), and ran it through AutoGK, making sure to select 700MB for the size.

Unfortunately the end result was *not* 700MB in fact, at 660MB, it was not even *sort of close*. I tried a different one and got a 750MB file.

Whenever “the Scene” releases an (XviD) video, they always seem to get it almost exactly at the target size, give or take perhaps two three megabytes at most.

I was going to try AVIDemux, but the latest version doesn’t seem to be of much use for this. Yes, I have seen plenty of (overly) simple programs, including free ones, but I don’t trust their quality—even though the converted files are temporary this time, I don’t want to have cheap, poor quality if I don’t have to.

How do they get such tight results?

Comment: If you can live with fixed bitrate encoding then all you have to do is calculate the bit rate needed to squeeze *x* seconds into *y* MB or *y ⨉ 8* MBit. Then, encode with that bitrate. However, I don't know the specifics of these moviez encodings. Ideally they should have some kind of guidelines on what encoder and which settings to use.

Comment: I have had good luck with MeGUI, but you need to use a bitrate calculator to get the size you want. Though trying to fit 6 full length movies on one dvd is really going to effect quality. http://sourceforge.net/projects/megui/

Comment: you might want to use MediaInfo to check videos you do have, it will give you complete information about the the video & audio...including what application was used to create the video. http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en

Comment: I believe [this scene rule](http://scenerules.irc.gs/t.html?id=2009_XViD.nfo) would be of interest to you.

Comment: @slhck, that looks promising (if lengthy). I’ll give it a try.

Comment: For the record, I ended up watching them on DVD. I’m still trying to get videos to encode to a consistent file-size…